# Is there a way to backup credentials of email settings on Google Nexus 7?

Tags: email, credentials, nexus-7

I want to do a hard reset to restart my tablet and have a clean start with it.

But i don't want to reconfigure all the emails.

Is there a way to simply hard reset and save the email credentials ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Google do backup your phone system completely (not sure the frequency but they do), and if you do a factory reset and you start by signing in to Google, they will (or should) give you the option to restore your phone to last known state (downloading all apps, and all remembered stuff). If you hate entering your password on your phone you can also use something like Lastpass (I personally use it and love it, but I'm not affiliated with them in any way besides a happy user)

Comment: Thank you, decided to reconfigure manually everything anyways !